# How can I make compiled applescripts on $PATH be found and executed?

Tags: applescript

I have some short applescripts that I want to use as utility functions inside shell scripts-- for example, one returns the name of the frontmost application.  The scripts reside in a personal scripts directory that is on my `$path`.  When in another directory, I can just run

```
$myscript.applescript
```

And, because the scripts directory is on the path, this file will be found and executed (at the top is `#!/usr/bin/env osascript`).  However, when I run

```
$myscript.scpt
```

To try and run the compiled version, I get:

> zsh: exec format error: get_front_app_name.scpt

I would like to use the compiled version but would also like to be able to run these like any executable on my `$path`, that is, without having to specify the interpreter name (`osacompile`) or the path to the file.  As of now, the only way I can see to execute the compiled .scpt applescript is to do both:

```
$osascript path/to/myscript.scpt
```

Is it possible to run the compiled form without this baggage?

Answer (score 1):

Since .scpt are not executable you won't be able to do this.

The shebang (!#) is not in the AppleScript syntax and therefore it won't do anything.

Comment: Applescript shebang is : #!/usr/bin/osascript

Comment: That's not an Applescript, that's a shell script starting an AppleScript.

Comment: But you can use it in a compiled applescript and plain text file. It allows you to run any Applescript using it's native syntax. But yes it will not run without the osascript command. P.S I marked you back up was trigger happy.

Comment: In a compiled AppleScript ? How would you do that ? Adding it to the AppleScript ByteCode just messes up the file.

Comment: No. I am incorrect. You are right the shebang is not for compiled Applescript just the plain text un compiled form to allow the script to use native applescript and as a shell scriptI knew this and was just being thick.

Comment: Not a big deal :)